# JQuery hide a div if a button contain specific class name

Tags: jquery

I have a page with popup window. when popup window is open it has some buttons with class of 'ui-state-disabled'. and if someone trying to click outside of popup box i want to close/hide that box ONLY if button has classname of 'ui-state-disabled'. but some times popup box has several buttons with 'ui-state-disabled' class, in that case if the 'ui-state-disabled' count is 1 popup can close by clicking outside.

below is my code. and its not working when multtiple  buttons has 'ui-state-disabled' class. please advice

```
  $(document).on('click', function (e) {

    if (($(e.target).closest(".classChapter").length === 0)) {
        if ($('div.buttonclass').hasClass('ui-state-disabled') === true) {
         //close a dialog box
        } else {
             console.log(2);
        }


    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second if

```
if ($('div.buttonclass').hasClass('ui-state-disabled') === true) {
```

can be

```
if ($('div.buttonclass.ui-state-disabled').length === 1) {
```

Comment: <div class="buttonclassc ui-state-disabled"><span class="canceltrigger">check this</span></div><div class="buttonclass @Aswin Ramesh ui-state-disabled"><span class="canceltrigger">another one</span></div>  I have two divs with same class, I want to trigger a command if only all divs with calss ='buttonclass ' doesnt have the 'ui-state-disabled' pls advice

Comment: `$('div.buttonclass').length !== $('div.buttonclass.ui-state-disabled').length` did you mean some thing like this?

Comment: what i want is to check if all 'buttonclass' divs has class called 'ui-state-disabled'

Comment: so you can `$('div.buttonclass').length === $('div.buttonclass.ui-state-disabled').length`